# user.name is undefind mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to show user names in posts who posted this on this website. I am successful in find users and also passing data to ejs temple and also getting user data by using ejs tag `<%= user%>` but when I call `<%=user.name%>` it say undefined also try to call like `.username` and `email` it's also undefined.
Here is ejs code

```
<p>Contributed by <span><%=user.name%></span> <span><%=post.date%></span></p>
<%= console.log(user.username)%> // user.name and user.email is undefined 
<%= console.log(user)%>// user is working and show all data which is store in MongoDB
```

Here is MongoDB schema for the user

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String ,
      email:String,
      password:String,
      profile:{data: Buffer,contentType: String}
    }
```

app.js route for finding data and render to posts page

```
app.get("/posts/:id", async (req,res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const post = await Post.findOne({ _id: id });
  const comments = await Comment.find({ post: id });
  const user = await User.find({_id: post.user});/// I have store user id into post schema 

  console.log(user)// getting user data 
  console.log(post.user)// getting user id from post
  res.render('posts', {
    post: post,
    comments: comments,
    user: user
  });// successfully render data to ejs 
      
});
```

Comment: You need to add more details in the question like how and what you are passing to the ejs render, your db call etc

Comment: I have added some more code

Comment: thanks, I have tried a lot accessed by user.name, but not access, also I have accessed all other like the post.Title, post.content . but in user. name I am unable to access. let me read mongoose docs.

Comment: yes , i  have solve it by using findById({}).

Answer (score 1):

i have solved it by using `User.findById({})` instead of `User.find({})`

```
const user = await User.findById({_id: post.user});
```